# Feature layer (AGOL) export to Excel failure?

Tags: arcgis-online, export, excel, arcgis-collector

When I try to export data from an AGOL feature layer into an xlsx i receive the following error.

"Excel cannot open the file, file format or extension is not valid"

When selecting to export you don't get an option to select the extension so I don't understand why this should be an issue.

Can anyone suggest a reason why this is happening or a work around?

For information :
The data been exported is a point feature with 3 text attribute fields.

Comment: So what is created?

Comment: Can you share the layer item with export enabled?

Comment: creates a .xlsx that cannot open (The error mention above is what is generated)